# Search for most favourited / most replied-to questions

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions, active

Why does Stackoverflow have no option to search for questions with most answers or having most favourites? This would be a nice feature as a tab, 'active' topics or similar.

I am constantly on a lookout for interesting topics (often unrelated to a particular technology) and the hottest topics seem to be the most interesting.

Comment: ...or questions with the most views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most answer questions, you could do this way,

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers:100

It will filter the search results to questions with 100+ answers

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because Stack Overflow was not meant to be browsed, it was meant for you to come, ask a question, and get great answers.

However, I grant you this vision could have changed since they went live almost one year and a half ago, and what you suggest could be debated.